# What's the best approach to save data to room when app is completely closed at a specific time in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-room

I have a simple Android app I have been working on for a few weeks.

The app is a diary to which you can set tasks you have to complete.

I need the app to have a functionality in which it will save an object to room at 12:00 am while the app is either open, open in the background, or completely closed.

My question to you is what do you think would be the best and most efficient approach for building this feature?

Thank you

Comment: "I need the app to have a functionality in which it will save an object to room at 12:00 am while the app is either open, open in the background, or completely closed." -- why? If the app is not running, nothing can tell whether the database contains this new data or not.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly at 12am, or could it be a few mins before or after?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best fit for this might be WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

You are basically abstracting out most of the other obvious choices, like AlarmManager, Services (background/foreground) - WorkManager lets the OS pick the best approach for your device and you only have to define it once.

Scheduling for specific times like you want is covered here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#schedule_periodic_work

Comment: `WorkManager` does not support scheduling work for specific times.

Comment: Bit hacky, I know, but all you have to do is pull the current system time, calculate the difference to midnight and schedule your first job. Then set it to 24 hour intervals from there. You're right that the API doesn't support out of the box scheduling for specific times, but you can basically play with the params to get the same result anyway...

Comment: I suppose a background service is also a viable approach, but that would have to run constantly and wouldn't be great for battery life... So probably not efficient like OP asked for

Comment: "but all you have to do is pull the current system time, calculate the difference to midnight and schedule your first job" -- you can specify an initial delay, which can be ignored. Quoting the documentation that you linked to, "The exact time that the worker is going to be executed also depends on the constraints that are used in your work request and on system optimizations".

Comment: True, it wouldn't be exact, on the nose. But my (admittedly limited) experience puts it at about +/- 15 minutes for these jobs to fire. Would you suggest AlarmManager for the initial trigger then?

Comment: "But my (admittedly limited) experience puts it at about +/- 15 minutes for these jobs to fire" -- [I would not count on that](https://dontkillmyapp.com/). "Would you suggest AlarmManager for the initial trigger then?" -- overall, I recommend avoiding background work to the greatest extent possible. That is why I asked the question that I did in my comment on the question itself. It is unclear why this work needs to be done at midnight.

Comment: I hear ya on the background stuff as a dev, but these reqs are often on the spec/stakeholder end. WM is essentially the compromise Google wants us to live with

Comment: Scope wise if I had to guess, I think this app is checking at midnight for unsaved/unresolved tasks or diary entries and then saving to DB, presumably to trigger a notification the next morning. There's smarter ways to handle it but OP said it's a simple app so I presume spec is kept that way on purpose